If someone falsely claims to have a Ph.D. on the jacket of a book and they profit from that claim, is that criminal fraud?
Say someone had started a Ph.D. but failed to complete, and wrote a book presenting themselves as an expert in their field, and claimed on the jacket to have a Ph.D.
The book sells many copies, and helps establish them as an expert in their field, leading to a lucrative career in consultancy and speaking events, i.e. they profit substantially from the book.
Would this be criminally actionable fraud?  What could the consequences be?  Are there any examples of this kind of thing happening and the person facing legal consequences?  Would the publisher of the book be liable too?
This is for a book published in the US.

I guess this is a follow up to Is it common or appropriate to use the phrase 'A Ph.D. in Subject X' to describe someone who has been a PhD student without earning the degree?

Not a lawyer at all, but it feels for a criminal case you'd need a lot clearer of a causal link between the fraudulent action and the commercial success. I.e., how do you prove that the commercial success was specifically because of the fraudulent claim (and not just because the book is good and the author is a decent speaker)?

@xLeitix At least in my jurisdiction (England & Wales) you merely have to intend to make a gain. Not only is it unnecessary to establish a causal link between the act and the gain, there doesn't even have to be any gain at all. E.g. if you lie about your salary on a mortgage application and the lender declines your application, that can still be fraud even though you didn't gain anything. More generally, fraud happens the instant you do the act and have the necessarily state of mind while doing it. What happens afterwards is irrelevant.

Is the author claiming to have an earned Ph.D from a certain institution, or just ",Ph.D." at the end of their name? Two arguably shady ways to actually have a Ph.D.: 1) An honorary Doctorate from a reputable institution, which does not imply any rigorous work. 2) Degrees that can be basically bought from non-recognized institutions.

He might also work for Pizza Hut Delivery or have a Public Highschool Diploma.

The U.S. Uniform Commercial Code (UCC) may be closer to an answer.  Having established that it is false advertising (and there may be state-specific laws on this and, assuming the product crossed state lines,etc.).
However there may be a case based upon merchantability of the product.  Specifically, it sold the information it contained, that advertised as written by someone with a Ph.D.  The value of the information upon which you can act is now much less that it was discovered to not have been written by a Ph.D. That is someone who achieved the highest degree possible in a field.  Thus it is just an uneducated opinion.
However, unless you acted upon the information, and it was blatantly wrong and you incurred other damages, the most you might be able to recover is the cost of the book.  And even then it might cost you more to recover it.
However, a class action suit is designed for this type of situation, where the individual harm is small, but there are many. Such as the price of a book, but the publisher makes millions because they sell millions of books.

A book with a misattributed author is almost never a non-merchantable book within the meaning of the UCC.

The value of the information upon which you can act is now much less that it was discovered to not have been written by a Ph.D. — that is an arguable claim.  Thus it is just an uneducated opinion. — this is even more questionable.  And there are many people with PhDs who write books on topics that aren't remotely in their field of expertise, for example, people with PhDs in Business Administration writing books denying climate change, evolution, or historical facts.

I've seen far more publications by people who do have degrees in the field they're covering who write nonsense for political or other ideological reasons (or merely financial gain) than such by people without such credentials.

Not to get too I blame society!-ish, but if there were fewer people saying complete falsehoods like "a book written by someone without a PhD is just an uneducated opinion", there'd be a lot less incentive for people to falsely claim to hold them.

I should have mentioned the obvious. In this case, the author LIED about his educational attainment. Is it reasonable to assume that the information contained in the book true? Hence the marketability of the book is greatly diminished.

united-states
In U.S. law, this probably wouldn't be the basis for a civil action unless the publication was such that the author having a PhD was a necessary part of its value (e.g. an expert witness report in a court case). This would, however, be almost entirely a matter of state law, rather than federal law, so the answer might not be 100% uniform across every U.S. state and jurisdiction.
There is a long tradition of pseudonymous publications in U.S. history, going all of the way back to the Federalist Papers. Generally, this practice, or other misrepresentations about who wrote something, isn't actionable (a different analysis might apply if you were selling, e.g., an allegedly original journal purportedly written by a famous person that would be virtually worthless but for its authentic connection to the famous person, i.e. where the buyer is buying the authorship and not the content itself and only the authorship is material). While like of liability in these circumstances isn't necessarily compelled by the First Amendment to the U.S. Constitution, it is colored by that tradition.
For example, the book "Rich Dad Poor Dad" (1997) by Robert T. Kiyosaki and Sharon Lechter, is full is major misrepresentations about Kiyosaki's personal experiences which are a core part of the argument that the book makes for the personal finance advice that it gives. But this is not actionable in U.S. law.
Unlike Germany, the U.S. has almost no statutory regulation of when academic and professional titles can be used beyond common law fraud. But, common law fraud sets a high bar to claims.
Generally, if the book is the book that the title proclaims it to be (and not, for example, a knockoff of another real book with a misrepresented title and author written by a third-party's AI), a misrepresentation of the author's identity or credentials will not constitute a material misrepresentation of fact for purposes of common law fraud, which is an element of that claim.

Makes me think of the Million Little Pieces controversy - Random House was sued by (and settled with) readers who felt defrauded by the author's claimed identity and the book's misrepresentation as a true memoir. Although that's an unusual case where the author's identity is inextricably entwined with the material, even more so than Kiyosaki as you mention. The personal identity of an author won't usually be as relevant to the book itself.

I'm waffling on whether there's a uniform federal answer. My first thought is that lies are generally protected by the First Amendment, but then my next thought is that that's less true in the context of commercial speech, but then my next thought is that the only commerce here is the sale of pure speech, so we may be back to the beginning. Not sure how it would shake out.

@NuclearHoagie oftentimes corps will settle even if the case against them is legally dubious if the settlement amounts to a pittance, particularly when compared to the amount it would cost to fight it out in court (along with the potential for bad press).  looks like MLP is a pretty good example of this, given the actual refunds only cost them at most about 20k, with the bulk of their hit being lawyer fees (~1 mil).  FIghting it in court, even if it was extremely likely or even guaranteed they would win would have cost much more, along with dragging out the controversy.

Just to provide an example of a state law which prohibits this, Texas PCC 7.32.52 disallows using a fictitious postsecondary degree "in a written or oral advertisement or other promotion of a business."

@Brian I wonder if authorship alone is an advertisement or a promotion of a business. A book isn't generally considered a business and advertisement arguably is modified by "business" and not just "other promotion"

germany has a specific criminal offense for this (§132a StGB, abuse of titles, job designations, and insignia). The job designations in this law are an enumerated set like "physician" or "lawyer," but there is a blanket prohibition of false academic titles.

There is currently an investigation against the new head of the department of economic affairs in the state of Brandenburg, Daniel Keller, who has actually finished his bachelor degree, but used the title in a CV published on his website before he received the certificate from his university. Apparently we take this law really seriously here in Germany.

@EikePierstorff that sounds more like a political witch hunt than anything else to me. If he graduated and put that title on his resume before he got the official paperwork in the mail he had the title as far as pretty much every reasonable person is concerned. When I graduated myself I got a piece of paper signed by the responsible people, the nicely embossed diploma took a week or so. Didn't mean I wasn't a graduate.

@jwenting of course it is. But the detractors are technically correct, the rules are that the title is applicable only after the certificate is received, so the state cannot just ignore it after receiving s complaint. This will have no legal consequence, but the damage to Keller's reputation is done which I agree with you was the point.

@jwenting I got the nicely embossed diploma first after a few weeks, and then the diploma to actually share (it was in pre-wide-internet times) some 6 months later. I started to use the title right after the defense, when I was officially addressed as doctor by the jury.

@WoJ I got them all together, took about 2 weeks. Also pre-internet.

@jwenting: after my PhD defense there was a recitation block including that "from now on, you are not any more required to correct someone calling you a Dr, but you may not use it yourself until the university has actually conferred the degree and you have the certificate". So it's not really an unknown obscure legal duty, putting a degree on the website before he had the degree is either rather a bold move done knowingly, or shows a level of absence of mind that makes one think about fitness for the office... It's still is a witch hunt, of course.

england-and-walesnorthern-ireland
It is capable of being fraud. Whether it is or not depends on the author's state of mind.
It will be fraud if all of the following elements are met under Section 2 of the Fraud Act 2006:

The claim to have a PHD is untrue or misleading
The author knew that it was, or might be, untrue or misleading
They made the claim dishonestly
By making the claim they intended to make a gain to themselves or another or to cause a loss to another or expose another to a risk of loss

It seems likely in this case that all elements are satisfied, so it's probably fraud.
The consequences are set out in Sections 1(3) and 1(4):

(3) A person who is guilty of fraud is liable —
(a) on summary conviction, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding
the general limit in a magistrates’ court or to a fine not exceeding
the statutory maximum (or to both);
(b) on conviction on indictment, to imprisonment for a term not
exceeding 10 years or to a fine (or to both).
(4) Subsection (3)(a) applies in relation to Northern Ireland as if
the reference to 12 months were a reference to 6 months.

It's less likely that the publisher would be guilty of fraud if they simply took the author at their word. It would only be fraud if all of the above elements also applied to the publisher.

Any idea on the comparable US law?  And it would be possible for someone (say someone who studied this subject area at university and was required to read the book with the fraudulent claim) to sue the author?

@AnonymousAcademic444 You don't sue people for criminal fraud; criminal means that the state prosecutes it (or doesn't). As for whether you have a civil fraud case - it seems doubtful. You'd need to show particular damages that were directly caused by the deception.

A big issue in my mind would be the materiality of the statement.

You might be able to sue for the price of the book, if you bought the book thinking they had a PhD but it turned out they didn't.

@StuartF Even then, you'd have to sue for the price of the book reduced by the resale price of selling it used.

@ohwilleke  you win the case, proving that it was fraud to sell you the book containing false claims, and then you are forced to sell the same book yourself? That seems an unreasonable expectation.

@Mark Mitigation of damages is a core common law rule. Disclose that he isn't a PhD in the ad if you are worriesdabout fraud.

Note that in the UK "Dr" is not a protected title, so if you describe yourself as "Dr X" you'd be fine. Unless you're Gillian McKeith.

So, does this mean I should stop using it instead of writing out my full job title - Pointy-haired Detective?

This is clearly fraud
While the nuances differ between jurisdictions, the essence of fraud is dishonestly obtaining benefit by wilful deception. The situation you describe ticks all the boxes.
In addition, this is misleading and deceptive conduct (MDC) which violates consumer protection law in many jurisdictions even if it is not dishonest or wilful.
Fraud is a serious crime which can carry substantial prison time. MDC is an offence usually punishable by fines.
Your question reminded me of the case of Neil Lennie. In 2021, when Lennie was 72 and retired, he pled guilty to four counts of Obtaining a Financial Advantage by Deception and sentenced to 3 months suspended and A Community Corrections Order.
Lennie had been a teacher for over 40 years starting in the 1970s, by all accounts an outstanding one, finishing with nearly two decades as the successful headmaster of a prestigious Victorian private girls school. However, he had never completed and undergraduate education and had never been registered to teach in Victoria (or anywhere else). The deceptions had been saying he was on the applications for the four teaching jobs he held over his career and the financial reward was the salaries he had been paid.
